# OS X not booting after upgrading LibXML2

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I tried upgrading the version of LibXML2 in my machine to run some propietary software. Compiled as 32-bit (-arch i386) and restarted to see if it worked. Now when I try to boot I can only get into the spinning screen and it just sits there.

Restarting in verbose mode (Cmd-V) does not show any error in the process, it just freezes after "AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: initialization complete". I can't from any CD either (if I press c on startup it just spins the disk around and then stops in the same spinner screen).

I've also reset the PRAM/NVRAM to discard any problems with that and it´s still not fixed.

Any pointers of what might´ve gone wrong?

(Latest gen MBP, running 10.6.3)

Answer (score 2):

libxml is pretty much fundamental to OS X since plists are used all over the place, even for launchd and kernel extensions which are loaded right at system start up.

In my standard installation of Snow Leopard 10.6.3, libxml.2.2.dylib has been compiled for 3 architectures:

```
$ file /usr/lib/libxml.2.2.dylib
libxml2.2.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
libxml2.2.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libxml2.2.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
libxml2.2.dylib (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
```

My guess is you've only compiled it for i386 but something requires the 64-bit version?

I don't understand why booting from a CD won't work though since it doesn't go near any system files on your hard disk. Booting from CD does take a while, did you leave it long enough?

Comment: This is why MacPorts and Fink smartly install their own versions of things under /opt and /sw respectively. This is a lesson Homebrew is learning as well.

Comment: I think the CD boot is not related directly to this, I've alway had issues with that. I'll try to restore the file today via FireWire or something and update the question.

Comment: Also various apple functions might rely on the exact version of libxml that apple installs - if you need a later version install elsewhere